# Send periodicals via email

Tags: kindle, mobi, kindle-paperwhite

I have same RSS feeds, that I would like to read them via periodicals menu. I can create a .mobi file as need format for periodicals and send it to Kindle PW2 with usb cable or download it from a remote web server, it goes to periodicals menu as I need, but if I send same file it with email to kindle, it goes Docs. So how can I send file to periodicals with email way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is impossible.

Since the Kindle email service converts everything to a personal document, you must USB sideload in order to retain the periodical tag.

Answer (score 1):

Calibre can send mails for you. I'd recommend to check the fine documentation:

- http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/gui.html#connect-share
- http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#i-cannot-send-emails-using-app
- And a forum post about handling it: http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=213166

Update: and I'd recommend to check the source file for the recipe which is not working properly. It might not has the proper setting for the magazine type in it:

```
publication_type = 'magazine'
```

Another option to this is using the CLI tools of Calibre with a CLI mail client, e.g. from a shell script (if you are on *nix OS, like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/ebook-convert /path/to/NEWSPAPER.recipe /path/to/OUTPUT.mobi && \
    nail -a /path/to/OUTPUT.mobi -s WHATEVER <<<""
```

(I'm using this above solution myself.)

Comment: when I send file with email (with calibre or normal mail client) it goes to "Docs". I don't want this behaviour (as I told before).